# python sys.stdout.write() redirect

Tags: python, linux, http

i am redirecting a proxy server to my script which checks the URL, User-Agents etc and based on the checks it returns the user to specified URL.

now if i send a GET request back to the client it works, but it display only text version of the site with no css/images, this is part of the code which sends the request back to the client..

```
if l.startswith('User-Agent:') and ('Safari' in l):

    new = "http://www.yahoo.com"
    new_get = "GET" + " " + str(new) + " " + "HTTP/1.1" + "Status: 302" + "\r\n\r\n"
    sys.stdout.write(new_get)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

i have tried to set

```
new = "302:http://www.yahoo.com"
```

but does not work either...

any ideas??

**UPDATED:**

```
if l.startswith('User-Agent:') and ('Safari' in l):

    new = "http://www.yahoo.com"
    new_get = "GET" + " " + str(new) + " " + "HTTP/1.1" + "Status: 302" + "\r\n\r\n"
    uopen = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.yahoo.com")
    sys.stdout.write(uopen.read())
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

tried with urllib2 and its takes a lot of time for the browser to render the page..but same results..no images/css..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the client:

```
new_url = 'http://www.yahoo.com/'

print 'Status:', '302 Found'
print 'Location:', new_url
print
```

If instead you want to serve something directly to the client:

```
from shutil import copyfileobj
from sys import stdout
from urllib2 import urlopen

http_message = urlopen("http://www.yahoo.com")
copyfileobj(http_message, stdout)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you doing all this by hand? The Python standard library contains modules such as [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) and [`httplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html), and even [`SimpleHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html) to help you with tasks like these.

Comment: @kris: I meant you should use these libs to parse the request (instead of `startswith` and so on), but whatever. Anyway, that's all your code? You redirect all `GET` requests to `www.yahoo.com`? So why are you surprised images don't show up? They get redirected too.

Comment: @kris: They get redirected to `yahoo.com` and the browser fails while trying to show the HTML as an image (or parse the HTML as CSS), so it shows nothing instead. Use Firebug or the Chrome Dev Tools to see this in action.

Comment: yeah i saw that..thanks for the help i will look into urllib2 and httplib